# jQuery Accordion - will it scroll to the top of the open item?

Tags: jquery, accordion

With the jQuery accordion control, how can I have it scroll to an item I've selected when it is off the screen?

When:

- I have an accordion item with contents larger than the viewable window
- I scroll down to the second accordion item
- I click the second accordion item to display it
- The first accordion option collapses, and the second opens, but slides off screen.

Is there an option for the accordion to scroll to the second item?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try using the [scrollTo jQuery plugin](https://github.com/balupton/jquery-scrollto). It lets you do things like this:

```
$.scrollTo('div#foo'); // scroll the browser window so div#foo is in view
$('div#foo').('#bar'); // scroll within div#foo so #bar is in view
```

Bind `ScrollTo()` to the `accordionactivate` event, like this:

```
$('#youraccordion').bind('accordionactivate', function(event, ui) {
  /* In here, ui.newHeader = the newly active header as a jQ object
              ui.newContent = the newly active content area */
  $( ui.newHeader ).ScrollTo(); // or ui.newContent, if you prefer
});
```

When is the `accordionactivate` event triggered?

> Triggered after a panel has been activated (after animation completes). If the accordion was previously collapsed, `ui.oldHeader` and `ui.oldPanel` will be empty jQuery objects. If the accordion is collapsing, `ui.newHeader` and `ui.newPanel` will be empty jQuery objects.

References: [jQuery UI Accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate)

Comment: which plugin is it? Your link doesn´t go anywhere.

Comment: @Toydor, in the years since I wrote this answer, the jQuery plugins "repository", such as it is, was completely restructured (after being lost to a crash, if I recall). I updated the link to point to what I believe is the current version of the plugin.

Comment: FYI, the API for jQuery UI Accordion widgets has changed. The new event to use is `accordionactivate`: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate

Comment: Without the scrollto jquery plugin: `document.getElementById(content).scrollIntoView();` inside the `accordionactivate` event callback works

Answer (score 31):

It works for me and tested,

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        if(!$.isEmptyObject(ui.newHeader.offset())) {
            $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({ scrollTop: ui.newHeader.offset().top }, 'slow');
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ilyasnone/aqw613em/

Comment: This was perfect. I works with "collapsible: true" and "active: false". This should be the chosen answer. Not the one that was selected. the one up top doesn't work with "collapsible: true". Nice job

Comment: Well worded questions, and a great copy and paste answer. THANKYOU!

Comment: This is a great solution, the only thing that really worked well for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

As I want collapse to be true I added an if test to cancel out the error of all items being collapsed.  I also didn't want the header to be exactly at the top of the page, so I lowered the scrollTop location by 100:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ui-accordion").bind("accordionchange", function(event, ui) {
      if ($(ui.newHeader).offset() != null) {
        ui.newHeader, // $ object, activated header
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: ($(ui.newHeader).offset().top)-100}, 500);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the only code that worked from all the above.

Comment: In newer versions, use this syntax for binding: `$(".ui-accordion").on("activate", function (event, ui) {`

Comment: @Martin What is the point of the line `ui.newHeader,`? I'm not sure it's required.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is old, but none of the above worked as desired for me. This is how I accomplished it. The -50 was just in case this was going to appear in an iPad or iPhone webapp so that the page didn't scroll the top of the accordion header behind the status bar.

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
  collapsible: true,
  autoHeight: false,
  animated: false
});
$('.ui-accordion-header').bind('click',function(){
    theOffset = $(this).offset();
    $(window).scrollTop(theOffset.top - 50);
});
```

Comment: Yup, this works too. Thanks a lot! +1 for the `autoHeight` property. Your answer helped kill two birds with one stone :)

Comment: *Precisely* what was needed for my iPad popover-based help pages.  Thank you so much!  I'd vote you up x100 if I could!

Answer (score 3):

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604760/jquery-accordion-scroll-beginning-of-clicked-tab-to-the-top-doesnt-work-if-ex) answer by [techfoobar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/921204/techfoobar)

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: 0,
        animate: 300 // collapse will take 300ms
    });
    $('#accordion h3').bind('click',function(){
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            theOffset = $(self).offset();
            $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: theOffset.top - 100 });
        }, 310); // ensure the collapse animation is done
    });
});
```

It is working for me with above modification.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
                    heightStyle: "content",
                    collapsible: true,
                    activate: function (event, ui) {

                        try
                        {
                            var self = this;
                            theOffset = $(self).offset();
                            $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: theOffset.top - 100 });
                        } catch (e) {
                            alert(e);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with binding the event when you used the accordion click to close function. Adding just a single if statement fixed it thought.

```
$('#accordion').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
    if(!ui.newHeader.length) { return; }
  /* In here, ui.newHeader = the newly active header as a jQ object
              ui.newContent = the newly active content area */
  $.scrollTo( ui.newHeader ); // or ui.newContent, if you prefer
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution from Martin works great. However when you add this code it will scroll to the top always, no matter if your accordion is visible on the page or not.

If you want to scroll to the top only when your accordion content larger than the viewable window, then use next code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
    {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }

    $(".accordion-inner").bind("accordionchange", function(event, ui) {
      if ($(ui.newHeader).offset() != null) {
        if (!isScrolledIntoView(ui.newHeader))
        {
            ui.newHeader, // $ object, activated header
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: ($(ui.newHeader).offset().top)-100}, 500);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey did have the same issue. Here is what worked for me at least what seems the easiest way.
Using the scrollTo plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#youraccordionheader').click(function(){
            $.scrollTo(this)                                                 
        })
    });
</script>
```

Hope it might be of use for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the first answer and liked this option best because it is one function for all accordion panels. But, I noticed that I kept getting an error when trying to (re)close the same accordion panel - it would halt the script at this line in the ScrollTo plugin:

```
attr[key] = val.slice && val.slice(-1) == '%' ?
```

The val was returning empty, so I found another answer here that said to check for it empty and added / replaced this function - so it works now.

```
else{
var val = targ[pos];
// Handle percentage values
if(val) {
    attr[key] = val.slice && val.slice(-1) == '%' ?
    parseFloat(val) / 100 * max
    : val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this function on window.load

```
$(function() {
    var icons = {
    header: "ui-icon-circle-plus",
    activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-minus"
    };
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    icons: icons, autoHeight: false, collapsible: true, active: false,
    activate: function(event, ui){
        var scrollTop = $(".accordion").scrollTop();
        var top = $(ui.newHeader).offset().top;
     //do magic to scroll the user to the correct location

     //works in IE, firefox chrome and safari
        $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: scrollTop + top -35 }, "fast");
       },



    });

    });
```

perfectl wokring

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary scrollTo plugin, you can do that:

```
$('.accordionNormalitzador').bind('accordionactivate', function(event, ui) {
        $( ui.newHeader )[0].scrollIntoView(); 
    });
```