# How to force the page straight to the main content when the user start scrolling the page?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a full screen image at the top. the main content is just under the image. my goal is the page scroll straight to the main content when the user start scrolling the page. like [this website](http://demo.vellumwp.com/)

How should I accomplish this with jQuery?

Comment: You can do that by using accordion -- demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/NGye9/1/ -- click on Section 1 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604760/jquery-accordion-scroll-beginning-of-clicked-tab-to-the-top-doesnt-work-if-ex -- and then have an (On scroll function to trigger the accordion)

Comment: You may wish to consider using a jQuery plugin like [Waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). It's very easy to use and quite powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/mbxks428/) as example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".down").offset().top},
    'slow');
});
```

And added a second [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/pu036p60/) as first one has the issue that it's not possible to leave the bottom part using this approach. Though it could be nice to be kept in specific content, as second variety only scrolling once:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (currentScroll > lastScrollTop && 
       $(".down").data("visible") === "no") {
    $(".down").data("visible", "yes");

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".down").offset().top
    },
        'slow');

  } else {
    // upscrolling could be handled here
  }
  lastScrollTop = currentScroll;
});
```

With example HTML:

```
<div class="top>">scroll down</div>
<div class="down" data-visible="no">here we are</div>
```

So specific forced scrolls could be set/unset using e.g. data-attributes on the divs.